# Background-color not working CSS in Class

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have the following CSS code. For some reason, the background-color is not working. can somebody pls help?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--Inform the Browser that the document is HTML-->
<html  lang="en-US">



<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<head>

<style type="text/css">


.leftpane{

width: 20%;
height: 80%;
border-color: brown;
border-width: .25em;
border-style: double;
float: left;
margin-right: 1em
background-color: orange;

}



</style>
<title>Trying CSS </title>
</head>


<body>

<div class="leftpane">
hi hi hi
<br/>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to put semicolon after previous rule:

```
margin-right: 1em /* <------ ooops! */
background-color: orange;
```

Lack of `;` makes parser ignore everything following after, so `background-color: orange;` is never considered.

Answer (score 0):

semicolon is missing before the background-color, Please correct it, Give semicolon to

```
margin-right: 1em;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using correct **CSS** syntax....

```css
.leftpane {
  width: 20%;
  height: 80%;
  border-color: brown;
  border-width: .25em;
  border-style: double;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftpane">
  hi hi hi
  <br/>
</div>
```